# focusable row inside table android

Tags: android, tablerow, focusable

i have in xml a ScrollView which includes one TableLayout.
My question is if it's possible to have a focusable row every time i click on it.
Here is my xml code:

```
    <ScrollView 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/table2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TableRow>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rowlayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbackground2" >
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_code_contact" 
                            android:padding="7dip"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/contacts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="Contacts"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="18dip"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                            android:paddingTop="10dip" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>


            <TableRow>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/contacts_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/contact_button" />
            </TableRow>
```

I have already tried the "focusable="true"" and "focusableInTouchMode="true"" but nothing happened..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 25):

If you are asking about how to make table to behave like ListView, I did the following:

In xml-file, which defines layout for my Activity, I defined the table:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_table"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, I wrote separate `table_row_item.xml` file with table row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_1"
        ...
    />
    ...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_N"
        ...
    />
</TableRow>
```

In Activity I declared procedure to add a row to my table:

```
private void addTableRow() {
    final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_table);
    final TableRow tr = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row_item, null);

    TextView tv;
    // Fill out our cells
    tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_1);
    tv.setText(...);
    ...
    tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_N);
    tv.setText(...);
    table.addView(tr);

    // Draw separator
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80808080"));
    tv.setHeight(/*height of separaor line. 2dip will be enough*/);
    table.addView(tv);

    // If you use context menu it should be registered for each table row
    registerForContextMenu(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GridView and define a LinearLayout (horizontal) as your row. Use this as a guide: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Row has onClick property where you can specify the name of your onclick method.

Other way is to give this row an id - name in your xml. Then you can call it from code and add onClick event.

Comment: I have already done what you said about row id but it didn't work..
My problem is that i can't make the row focusable when it's clicked//

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by fucusable, do you mean that it should show it is selected? Because you have a relative layout within the row it could be that some other view receives the focus when you click. Perhaps other inner views should have false for clickable...

Answer (score 0):

This code will flip between your choosen drawable background (I guess you can use null to have no background) and the default Android "selected" background.

```
    row.setClickable(true);
    row.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            Log.d("Touched!", "" + action);
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                // case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_bottom);
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            default:
                v
                        .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                v.invalidate();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple and effective solution for displaying data in a table this [TableView](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView) will do the job.

[image: SortableTableView Example]