# Is any normal table view in Android?

Tags: android, jtable

I need to build something like this

[image]

but in Android. How to create table (like JTable in swing), which will have:

1. static headers
2. clickable rows (like ListView element)
3. scrollable content

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a component like this on Android. You should create a `ListView` with the content rows and above a layout with the header row. And make the column division on the layout that you will use to represent each row on the ListView.

Other way is create a `TableLayout` inside a scroll, like this answer suggests: [focusable row inside table android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873556/focusable-row-inside-table-android/5258310#5258310)