# ListView.onItemLongClick - get item's element

Tags: android, get, row

I created linearlayout with textviews which is ListView's row (because I need a table: [Is any normal table view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307586/is-any-normal-table-view-in-android)). It's layout sample of listview's row:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/first_name"
         android:layout_width="100dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/last_name"
         android:layout_width="100dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/experience"
         android:layout_width="100dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/birthday"
         android:layout_width="100dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I need to get every field's value of selected row. I'm try

```
   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workers_list);
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                alert(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()); // alert is Toast
                return true;
            }
        });
```

but it returns all data in interesting(?) data format:
[image]
how to get not all data of row, but only some column's value?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you asking if it is possible to detect which "column" in your list item was long pressed, or simply how to access a specific field in the model object that you retrieved with `getItemAtPosition()`?

Comment: Can you post what kind of adapter you are using, possibly all you need to do is change the tostring method

Comment: I want not array as at picture from parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(). I want something like parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getString("birthday"), which will return "Дата народження", or parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getString("first_name"), which will return "Імена" and etc. I need to get  
concretely TextView's value of concretely adapter's row, which binded on some listview.

Comment: nandeesh, sure.      WorkersListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, WorkersArrayList, R.layout.listview_row,
       new String[] {"first_name", "last_name", "experience", "birthday", "job", "academic_degree", "academic_title", "operative_rank"}, new int[] {R.id.first_name, R.id.last_name, R.id.experience, R.id.birthday, R.id.job, R.id.academic_degree, R.id.academic_title, R.id.operative_rank});
     list.setAdapter(WorkersListAdapter);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getItemAtPosition` returns the Map at the position. So You could do

```
((Map)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).get("birthday").toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use table, then you can use table layout