# Programatically give space between buttons in table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a activity like this.

![Image][1]

Here start ,complete and delivered are buttons`.how to give space between buttons.?`

Below is my code.

i have a table layout designed in `.xml` and since its data is dynamic i am adding rows programatically.

```
/*** xml code ****/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView         android:id="@+id/title_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/timg"/>

    <TextView   android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="63dp"
                        android:text="Alpha Restaurant"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_image"
                        android:background="#ED4040"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="35sp"/>

      <TextView         android:id="@+id/tbno"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:text="Kitchen Dashboard  :"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#05539C"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

     <TextView  android:id="@+id/tvtbno"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tbno"
                        android:text="KIT01"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#05539C"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

     <TextView  android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:text="Time :"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvtbno"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#05539C"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

     <TextView  android:id="@+id/tvtime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time"
                        android:text="KIT01"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#05539C"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

     <TextView  android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:text="Date :"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvtime"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#05539C"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

     <TextView  android:id="@+id/tvdate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                        android:text="KIT01"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textColor="#05539C"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

     <ScrollView        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="370dp"
                                android:id="@+id/sc" android:layout_below="@+id/tvdate">

    <TableLayout  android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                          android:layout_below="@+id/tbno"
                          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                  android:layout_height="550dp"  
                  android:shrinkColumns="*"  
                  android:stretchColumns="*">  

    <TableRow  
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
                  android:background="#A9D0F5"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                  android:layout_width="match_parent">  

    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv1"  
                  android:text="Lot No"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>
    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv2"  
                  android:text="Item"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>  

    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv3"  
                  android:text="Quantity"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv4"  
                  android:text="Order"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>
    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv5"  
                  android:text="Notes"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv6"  
                  android:text="Start"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv7"  
                  android:text="Completed"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView  
                  android:id="@+id/tv8"  
                  android:text="Delivered"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                  android:textSize="20dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  
                  android:textColor="#190710"
                  android:typeface="serif"/>
    </TableRow>  

    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- <TextView      android:id="@+id/total"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Total : "
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"/>

    <TextView   android:id="@+id/tvtotal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="500 Rs"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"/>-->

    <Button     android:id="@+id/refresh"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Refresh"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="340dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/sc"/>

     <Button    android:id="@+id/home"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Home"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/refresh"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/sc"/>  

</RelativeLayout>


/**** java code ****/

@Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean a) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPostExecute(a);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        int count= 0;

                        try{
                        allarray = new JSONArray(result);
                        System.out.println("array is " +allarray.length());
                        JSONObject json_data=null;
                                for(int j=0;j<allarray.length();j++){
                                json_data = allarray.getJSONObject(j);
                                json_data.getString("PreparationLot");
                                json_data.getString("Prep_MenuItem");
                                json_data.getString("Prep_Quantity");
                                json_data.getString("Prep_Order_Number");
                                json_data.getString("Prep_Notes");

                                TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

                        TableRow tr = new TableRow(DashBoard.this);
                        if(count%2!=0) {
                                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(222, 219, 219));
                        }else{
                                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                        }
                        tr.setId(20);
                        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams());

                        final TextView lotno = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                        lotno.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                        lotno.setText(""+json_data.getString("PreparationLot")); // set the text for the header
                        lotno.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                        lotno.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                        lotno.setTextSize(14);
                                tr.addView(lotno);

                                final TextView itemname = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                                itemname.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                                itemname.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_MenuItem")); // set the text for the header
                                itemname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                                itemname.setMaxLines(3);
                                itemname.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                                itemname.setTextSize(14);
                                tr.addView(itemname);

                                TextView qty = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                                qty.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                                qty.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_Quantity")); // set the text for the header
                                qty.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                                qty.setPadding(50, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                                qty.setTextSize(14);
                                tr.addView(qty);

                                TextView order = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                                order.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                                order.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_Order_Number")); // set the text for the header
                                order.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                                order.setPadding(40, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                                order.setTextSize(14);
                                tr.addView(order);

                                TextView notes = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                                notes.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                                notes.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_Notes")); // set the text for the header
                                notes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                                notes.setPadding(40, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                                notes.setTextSize(14);
                                tr.addView(notes);

                            final Button start = new Button(DashBoard.this);
                            start.setText("Start");
                            start.setMaxWidth(10);
                            start.setTextSize(16);
                            start.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            start.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        tr.addView(start);

                        final Button complete = new Button(DashBoard.this);
                        complete.setText("Complete");
                        complete.setMaxWidth(10);
                        complete.setTextSize(16);
                        complete.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        complete.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        tr.addView(complete);

                        final Button delivered = new Button(DashBoard.this);
                        delivered.setText("Delivered");
                        delivered.setMaxWidth(10);
                        delivered.setTextSize(16);
                        delivered.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        delivered.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        tr.addView(delivered);

                                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

               count++;

}
```

Comment: Try this.. android:shrinkColumns="7"
 android:stretchColumns="1". Instead of (*) you have written and please let me know the result

Comment: and then you can give the padding or margin whatever you want

Comment: @nick i have to do it progrmatically...

Comment: I think after adding the view on the tl,you have to set the margin

Comment: tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); After this line you have to set the margin. In my case to draw the separator I used this step

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5258310/1395259  .please read this link

Comment: Goofy why dont you want to go with the xml. Any reson

Comment: @nick how is that? i can implement...

Comment: See the basic funda is the seperation right. So just draw an ImageView Between Two Buttons like this.   <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

Comment: @nick i am adding the buttons progrmatically ...

Comment: So you can add the ImageView also programatically na

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19938/discussion-between-goofy-and-nick)

Answer (score 1):

add your buttons using following code,
and if you want to increase the space then increase the leftMargin from 10 to 15 or 20.

```
            final Button start = new Button(DashBoard.this);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpButton = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) start.getLayoutParams();
            lpButton.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
                start.setText("Start");
                start.setMaxWidth(10);
                start.setTextSize(16);
                start.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                start.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                start.setLayoutParams(lpButton);
                tr.addView(start);

            final Button complete = new Button(DashBoard.this);
            complete.setText("Complete");
            complete.setMaxWidth(10);
            complete.setTextSize(16);
            complete.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            complete.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            complete.setLayoutParams(lpButton);
            tr.addView(complete);

            final Button delivered = new Button(DashBoard.this);
            delivered.setText("Delivered");
            delivered.setMaxWidth(10);
            delivered.setTextSize(16);
            delivered.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            delivered.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            delivered.setLayoutParams(lpButton);
            tr.addView(delivered);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to giving paddingLeft or paddingRight to the buttons. Besides you can give padding to a layout that wraps them.

Comment: You can add padding of every individual view in the TableRow of your code by doing this:
<pre>
    for(int i = 0; i < tr.getVirtualChildCount(); i++){
    tr.getVirtualChildAt(i).setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
}
</pre>