# Display all data to listview using a tableview format

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, tableview

Below is my database that I have already created and it works fine, it can save the data to the database,I am really new to this android project and need guidance on how to display all data that was saved inside the listview.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class BmiDatabase {

    private data helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase help;
    private Context context;

    public BmiDatabase(Context context){
        helper = new data(context);
        help = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.context=context;
    }

    public long insertData(String bmi, String status, String weight){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(data.NAME, bmi);
        contentValues.put(data._STATUS, status);
        contentValues.put(data.WEIGHT, weight);
        long id = db.insert(data.DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }
    public String getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] columns = {data.UID, data.NAME, data._STATUS, data.WEIGHT};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(data.DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
           // int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(data.UID);
           // int cid = cursor.getInt(index1);

            int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
            String bmi = cursor.getString(1);
            String status = cursor.getString(2);
            String weight = cursor.getString(3);
            buffer.append(cid +" "+bmi+" kg "+status+" "+weight+ "\n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }


    public static class data extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private Context context;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bmidatabase";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "bmitable";
        private static final int DB_VERSION = 7;
        public static final String UID = "_id";
        public static final String NAME = "Bmi";
        public static final String _STATUS = "Status";
        public static final String WEIGHT = "Weight";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE;

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                " "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255)," +
                " "+_STATUS+" VARCHAR(255)," +
                ""+WEIGHT+" VARCHAR(255));";

        public data(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            this.context=context;
        }


        public void getAllData(){

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try{
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                Message.message(context,"Database Created");
            }
            catch (SQLException e){
                Message.message(context, "Failed" +e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try{
                Message.message(context, "DATABASE DELETED");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                Message.message(context, "SQL FAILED");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the code for my mainactivity, it shows that I can display it using a toast, but I have no idea how to call the method to populate the list view with those data.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //private static DataHelper DataHelper;
    //DataHelper helper = new DataHelper(this);

    private static BmiDatabase data;

    private EditText weightinputid;
    private EditText heightinputid;
    private Button buttonBMI, save, detail;
    private TextView BMIStatus;
    private TextView BMIfinal;
    private double weight =0.0;
    private double height =0.0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //  setupDB();
      //  setDB();
        initializeApp();
    }

    private void initializeApp(){
        weightinputid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightid);
        heightinputid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heightid);
        buttonBMI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBMI);
        BMIfinal= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMIfinal);
        BMIStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMIstatus);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        detail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        data = new BmiDatabase(this);

    }
    public void calculateBMI (View v){

        String status;

        weight= Double.parseDouble(weightinputid.getText().toString());
        height= Double.parseDouble(heightinputid.getText().toString());

        double bmi = weight/(height/100*height/100);
        String result = String.format("%.2f", bmi);
        Log.d("MainActivity", result);
        BMIfinal.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);

        if(bmi < 16){
            status = "Seriously Underweight";
        }
        else if(bmi >=16.0 && bmi < 18.0){
            status = "Underweight";
        }
        else if(bmi >=18.0 && bmi <24.0){
            status = "Normal";
        }
        else{
            status = "Obese";
        }

        BMIStatus.setText(status);

    }
        public void save(View v){
            String bmi = BMIfinal.getText().toString();
            String status = BMIStatus.getText().toString();
            String weight = weightinputid.getText().toString();

        long id = data.insertData(weight, bmi, status);
        if(id<0)
        {
            Message.message(this, "");
        }
        else
        {
            Message.message(this, "");
        }

    }
    public void detail(View v){
        String d = data.getAllData();
        Message.message(this, d);
    }

    }
```

Comment: You have to display data in listview in a form that it looks like a table right ? use custom adapter & a custom listview items inside your list view

Comment: if I am right and you want to make the custom adapter this can help a bit: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: yes a list view that can display bmi, status, and weight but in a table format

Comment: u just have to make a custom listview item, take a look at the above given link that how he created a listview customize item

Comment: have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873556/focusable-row-inside-table-android/5258310#5258310

Comment: i will try to create it first, thanks

Comment: What is a `TableView`? There's no such component in Android. The one I can think of like a table is a `GridView`. But, more frequently, you'll just use  a custom `ListView`.